# Query in trigger doesn't give expected result

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I tried to get the following output through triggers in SQL Server 2005. I'm using this query to change the values of `age` (column name) to zero, if it is less than zero.

```
Create trigger agecheck 
on account 
for insert 
as begin
    Declare @age int

    select @age = age 
    from inserted 

    if @age < 0 
       set @age = 0;
```

end

I was able to execute this query successfully, but I'm not getting desired result. I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Could you please suggest on this.

Comment: Could you show some example, like the result that you get but which you do not want?

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing in your trigger is setting the variable `@age` to 0 if it was less than 0. Simply selecting the age into a variable like that, doesn't link that variable to your field in the table.

Not only that, the [`inserted` virtual table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) can have more than one row in it. Your select statement would only assign the last `age` returned from the query to the variable.

What you need to do is join the table that was inserted in, with the `inserted` virtual table on its primary key.

Assuming your `account` table has as its key `account_id`, that would give the following create statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER agecheck 
  ON account
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    account
  SET
    age=0
  FROM
    inserted AS i
    INNER JOIN account AS a ON
      a.account_id=i.account_id
  WHERE
    i.age<0
END
```